# How to get data from Google Sheet to use in deployed web app

Tags: google-apps-script

I am using Google App scripts and am having trouble finding an answer to this fairly simple task: how can I get the data from a Google Sheet in my code.gs and then use it in a published web app (for some visualization w/ D3)?

I would like to get all columns and rows from the spreadsheet, then use those in the data. Preferably they would be in JSON for ease of use, but I can't find the specifics on how to grab all (or any) of the data from a Sheet in my code.gs and then use it in the index.html.

So far I have something like this:

code.gs

```
function getData(){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1NCNsdEGAHXWhZMEHnOflsIqElKdQSQxy83iM5vUIa9k");

 //get desired range

 return sheet;
}
```

index.html

In the `<script>` in index.html:

```
 google.script.run.getData();
```

But am otherwise at a loss. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the data is fairly easy. However this has to be properly done on both server side and client side.

For **code.gs** you will need to return actual data, but currently `return sheet` just returns the sheet object. What you need to do instead is

```
var vals = sheet.getDataRange().getValues()
```

which now gets you a 2D array of your sheet values. Now keep in mind that `sheet` has to be a `sheet object` not a `spreadhseet object`. So if your spreadsheet has many sheets, make sure you get the correct one with something like

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1NCNsdEGAHXWhZMEHnOflsIqElKdQSQxy83iM5vUIa9k").getSheets()[0];
```

or

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1NCNsdEGAHXWhZMEHnOflsIqElKdQSQxy83iM5vUIa9k").getSheetByName('Sheet1');
```

Now, since you want to grab the data as a JSON, all you really have to do is

```
vals = JSON.stringify(vals)
```

and now you have a JSON string of values. However that is just half of it, because your `index.html` that you wrote will not make use of the data as it calls the server side function, but does not listen for a response. In order to do that, you will need to use a success handler as written [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run). Essentially you will have to call a function in `index.html` that will make use of the returned `vals` variable. So something like

```
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(useData).getData();

function useData(data) {
   data = JSON.parse(data)
   //now you have a 2D array in your index.html and you can use it as you wish within these client side scripts
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do I need to assign that final `google.script.run...` to a variable in my html? I'm having some difficulty debugging at the moment.

Comment: `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fooClient).fooServer()` calls `fooClient(ret)` function in your html where the return value of `fooServer()` from your .gs script is passed on as `ret` so you do not need to assign it to any variable (I don't think it's even possible or that it would do anything). You then process the return value inside the `fooClien(ret)` and put it anywhere in your html programatically just like with regular javascript on the webpage.

Comment: Right, I sort of came to that conclusion myself after some testing. Thanks!