# Is there an API for extracting grades in Google Classroom

Tags: google-classroom

I was reviewing the Google Classroom API and noticed there was not an option for getting grades.  I need to extract the assignment grades from Google Classroom into an external grade book app that I am creating.  Does anyone know if this is possible, or how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can definitely get grades from the API.

Classroom.Courses.CourseWork.StudentSubmissions.list(course.id, work.id).studentSubmissions

From there, loop through the studentSubmissions:
studentSubmissions[i].assignedGrade

That gets the assigned grade for that specific assignment. I also grab studentSubmissions.userId in order to get the student name. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks so much @Eliana-cohen, I'll give this a shot!  Much appreciated.

Comment: What if I have graded using a Rubric, and I wish to read the rubric split of the grade?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible with Google Sheets and Apps Script. You can [export your grades to Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/edu/classroom/answer/6020294?hl=en&ref_topic=9050121) and from there, you can use Apps Script to extract data from the sheets. To do that, you can check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175891/how-to-get-data-from-google-sheet-to-use-in-deployed-web-app) and the [methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet) to access and modify spreadsheet sheets.