# Is there an API for extracting rubric grading data in Google Classroom?

Tags: google-classroom

I have read a helpful post for grades...
[Is there an API for extracting grades in Google Classroom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161474/is-there-an-api-for-extracting-grades-in-google-classroom)

and the API for grading...
https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/manage-coursework#grade_student_responses

but haven't been able to see anything for rubric grading data yet. Or am I missing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, at this time, there isn't a way of getting Rubrics from the Classroom API.*

#### Feature Request:

There is already a report on Google's Issue Tracker which request this feature to be added to the API:

- [Add Rubrics to Classroom API](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/130443624)

It appears that Google does seem to know about this and has responded on the above feature request. What you can do it hit the ☆ next to the issue number in the top left on the aforementioned page - this lets Google know more people are wanting this feature to be implemented and so it is more likely to be seen to faster.