# Get overall grade from Google Classroom using Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-classroom

Using the Classroom API, one can get most of the information for students in a class.  I can't seem to find a way to get a current overall grade for students to then automatically populate a spreadsheet.  I know this can be done manually by exporting grades to a sheet or csv.  I also know that Classroom API allows for getting grades on specific submissions.  Is it possible to get overall grades with the Classroom API?

Comment: In your situation, is this thread useful? https://stackoverflow.com/q/53161474

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I read that thread and it is not what I'm looking for.  I wish to extract the overall grade and not assignment grades.  Theoretically, one could loop through each assignment and each submission and calculate an overall grade.  I'm surprised there is not a method for .getOverallGrade.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.  I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: I doubt my skill exceeds yours - lol.  But if forgiveness is necessary, it is thus granted :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have no code relevant to the question.